# Unable to Launch Application. Could not load file/url specified. How to rebuild shortcut?

Tags: java

I have a shortcut that has the following target property value:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\javaws.exe -localfile "C:\Users\MY_ID\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\27\18ee81b-674b0db6"
```

I get this error when I try doubel clicking on it:

```
Unable to Launch Application. Could not load file/url specified
```

I see that the above referenced file/folder does not exist on my PC (anymore?. This worked yesterday; I didn't think anything changed...

When I searched my PC for other similar shortcuts, I discovered another shortcut for this app that pointed to another user's cache

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\javaws.exe -localfile "C:\Users\someone_ELSE\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\27\18ee81b-674b0db6"
```

When I run it, I got the same error. However, when I ran it with Elevated Rights, it worked, however the shortcut under my own ID still failed even with Elevated Rights. 
When I look at the shortcut, I see that its target property points to a file that exists in the cache folder for that user. Apparently I needed Elevated Rights to be able to access it. That makes sense. However, what I don't understand is why my shortcut is now pointing to a missing file and how to rebuild my shortcut so that my DB2 Host Emulator Java program works.

I tried going into the Control Panel and under General->Settings UI unchecked "Keep Temp Files" and I clicked the "DELETE FILES" button and deleted everything, including APPS and APPLETS (now this option is disabled, probably because there is nothing left to delete.) However, doing this did not resolve the issue of not being able to launch the app using my old shortcut, the only way I could launch it is to run the shortcut that points to the cache file in another user's cache and that requires elevated rights, which I would prefer not to do. In fact, I'd like to delete this user's history entirely from my PC if possible and this issue stops me from doing so because I have no other way to run this app.

Out of desperation, I tried copying the referenced target file from the other user's cache folder as well as the associated similarly name file that is suffixed with ".idx" and placing it in my cached folder and pointing my shortcut to it did not work. I got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initially ran it, you would have run it on a file with a `.jnlp` extension; your system would then have downloaded the files from the web, and run them from the local cache. If you can find the `.jnlp` file you ran, you'll be able to run that again: it'll use the cache if it's still there, and it'll download again if not.

Comment: I found the file, "C:\Program Files\IBM\IBMHOD\HODIcons\CIGNA.jnlp", double clicked it & it updated my cache. Now, what is the "normal" way to re-launch it? By double clickin the jnlp file? I don't know that it matters as long as it works, but it is strange to me that now I am launching it with a different extension. Is there any drawbacks with launching it this way? I tried to identify the ".idx" file pair that was added to my cache. A few were. I tried to recreate my shortcut pointing to the 1st & had no luck. I've never seen shortcuts that point to cache files, I wonder how they were set up

Comment: It may be that you've got something installed somewhere that is a shortcut to that file, or launches it somehow. But double-clicking on it will launch it using `javaws`, which is the Right Thing To Do (TM), so it doesn't much matter.